# UITesting How to get a number that's a part of the tabBar section?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Sorry about the title, didn't really know how to word this question. Here's a picture to help:[image]

I want to be able to get that number "5" next to the Notifications tab into a variable and am struggling to do so. The "Notifications" tab is just this button

```
XCUIApplication().tabBars.buttons["Notifications"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `UITabBarItem` has a `badgeValue`

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue
```

Comment: To add on, for updating the amount of notifications you can see, just do: tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue++ or --

Comment: actually ++ has been deprecated since Swift 2.2. I would do something like tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue += 1

Comment: Had not realized that; will take a note

Comment: @guidev Hi sorry I am completely new to this stuff and am not too sure we're talking about the same thing. I am UITesting right now and don't need to update anything--just need to obtain values. I am not too sure how to obtain a UITabBarItem through code. My button does not have a badge value because it is of type XCUIElementQuery